# How to get this very simplified demographic forecast?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on the simulation of a population growth.
The variables and hypothesizes are the following:

- Lifetime: **X** years (X constant for everybody, yeah !)
- Initial population: **Y** people (with always 50% men, 50% women)
- Children per women per life: **Z** (don't take in account the puberty or menopause)
- The people from the initial population have different ages fairly divide in the  lifetime **X** (e.g. if the lifetime is 50 years and they are 100, you'll get 2 people per age)

I'm a beginner in mathematics and I'd like to know how to calculate the formula and then be able to display the evolution of this population for specifics X, Y and Z (population growth, birth per year, death per year, etc.).

The birth per year seems easy.
A woman gets **Z** children in **X** years so they have **Z/X** children per year.

I guess it should be calculated by something like:
$$
a_0 = Y
$$$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{Z}{X}*\frac{a_n}{2} - (deaths)
$$
But I don't know how to manage the deaths...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Z/X$ is just number of children per woman per year, so you should multiply it with number of women: $a_n/2$.

Death part is more difficult. Since everyone has constant lifetime, it is number of people born $X$ years ago. It is easy to find for first $X$ years, just $Y/X$, but after that it changes.

You could get better and easier model, if you say that everyone has chance to die during a year equal to $1/X$. That gives you average life expectancy of $X$.

Comment: Does this mean that every year you have death = a(n)/X ?

Comment: That's that. By the way, you should think and write down,  what additional assumptions do you make. For instance, do those formulas work, if this population behaves somewhat strangely? Suppose they die only in odd-numbered years? It is reasonable to guess they do not behave like that, but what is the assumption we make?